# Duda relacion en Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relaciones

Tengo 3 clases y una tabla pivote:

> **Centro:** id, nombre
>
> **Rol:** id, centro_id, nombre
>
> **Rol_usuario:** user_id, rol_id
>
> **User:** id, nombre

```
//Modelo Centro
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Centro extends Model
{
    public function roles(){
        return $this->hasMany(Rol::class);
    }
    
    public function users(){ //este método no me funciona
        return $this->roles->hasManyTrhough(User::class,Rol::class);
    }
}
```

```
//Modelo Rol
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;

class Rol extends Model
{
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function centro(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Centro::class);
    }

}
```

```
//Modelo User
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Rol::class);
    }

    public function centros(){ //este método no me funciona
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Centro',
            'App\Rol',
            'user_id',
            'rol_id',
            'id',
            'rol_id'
        );
    }

}
```

Lo que pretendo es crear, en el modelo `User`, un método `centros()` para que me devuelva todos los centros que están relacionados con ese usuario a través del rol, así como desde `Centro` poder ver las instancias de `User` con las que se relaciona a través del `Rol`.
He visto que existe el método `hasManyThrough` pero si no he entendido mal seria de Centro hacia `User`, pero no de `User` hacia `Centro`.

Ej: Un `User` `$usr` tiene dos roles, cada uno de ellos pertenece a un centro distinto. Si llamo a `$usr->roles` me aparecen los dos roles.
Si llamo a `$centro->roles` me aparece el rol relacionado a ese centro.
Con `$rol->centro` me devuelve el centro asociado con ese rol.
Llamando `$centro->users` me debería dar los usuarios que tienen asignados un rol que pertenece a ese centro. En cambio me da el error `Exception with message 'Property [users] does not exist on this collection instance.'`.
Con `$usr->centros` debería mostrarme aquellos centros relacionados con el usuario según los roles que este tiene asignados, pero me da el error

> BadMethodCallException with message 'Method
> Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection::belongsTo does not exist.`

¿Alguna pista de cómo crear esta relación?

Comment: Por lo que dices, lo único que tienes son los 3 modelos y una tabla pívot... Lo de las relaciones está todo por hacer o ya probaste algo? Te sugiero que agregues a la pregunta el código de los modelos, con tus intentos de definir las relaciones que mencionas, y si te encontraste con algun impedimento o no te funciona algo, que nos digas cual es el resultado esperado y cual es el resultado obtenido por lo cual no te funciona.

Comment: Exacto, 3 modelos y una tabla pívot. He añadido el código que tengo y comentado aquellos dos métodos que no me funcionan

Comment: La relación entre centro y rol funciona, la relación entre rol y user también funciona. La que no funciona es entre centro y user y entre user y centro. Edito la consulta añadiendo información

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasManyThrough` no te va a funcionar si la relación intermendia es muchos a muchos. Hay algunos enfoque que podrías probar, por ejemplo creando un modelo para la tabla pivot, definiendo las relaciones ahí, y luego aplicando `hasManyThrough` a través de ese modelo pivot.

Sin embargo, debería ser posible obtener los centros recorriendo todos los roles del usuario, creando una array de centros y devolviéndolo como una colección. No es exactamente definir una relación, sino hacer un método que use la relación ya definida para devolver los objetos relacionados a través de ella.

**User**:

```
/**
 * Obtener todos los centros a través de los roles al que el usuario pertenece
 *
 */
public function centros()
{
    // Aquí, creamos un array vacío.
    $centros = [];    
    // obtenemos los roles del usuario
    $this->roles()
        // recorremos los roles pasando el array de $centros como referencia para actualizarlo.
        ->each(function ($roles, $key) use (&$centros) {
            $centros[] = $roles->centro;
        });
    // devolvemos el array como colección
    return collect($centros);
}
```

Puedes usar esto en la aplicación así:

```
User::find($id)->centros();
```

Nota: Puedes devolver esto como un [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators) cambiando el nombre de la función a `getCentrosAttribute()`. Esto te permitirá acceder al campo centros así:

```
Usuario::find($id)->centros
```

**Centro**:

```
/**
 * Obtener todos los usuarios que pertenecen al centro a través de los roles
 *
 */
public function users()
{
    $users = [];    
    $this->roles()
        ->each(function ($roles, $key) use (&$users) {
            $users[] = $roles->centro;
        });
    return collect($users);
}
```

Puedes usarlo en la aplicación así:

```
Centro::find($id)->users();
```

Comment: Maravilloso, muchisimas gracias! Por cierto, entiendo que el nombre de la función debería ser `getCentrosAttribute()`. Muchas gracias, problema solucionado y a mi parecer muy elegantemente

Comment: Ah disculpa, cierto, get para un accesor, ahora lo corrijo.